# Jquery Argument to set Scroll height Dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the following jQuery function in which i need to pass an extra argument to access the height as a dynamic value. Is there any way to do that? My code so far is :

(need to get a value for the ScrollHeight)

```
(function (cash) {
$.fn.Scrollable = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        //ScrollHeight: 400,
        //Height:height,
        Width: 0
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var grid = $(this).get(0);
        //var doc = this.document.getElementById("height").nodeValue.toString();

        var gridWidth = grid.offsetWidth;

        var ScrollHeight = 400; //$(this).getElementById("height").Value; // height.toString();
        alert("");
        var headerCellWidths = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.getElementsByTagName("TH").length; i++) {
            headerCellWidths[i] = grid.getElementsByTagName("TH")[i].offsetWidth;
        }
        grid.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        var parentDiv = grid.parentNode;

        var table = document.createElement("table");
        for (i = 0; i < grid.attributes.length; i++) {
            if (grid.attributes[i].specified && grid.attributes[i].name != "id") {
                table.setAttribute(grid.attributes[i].name, grid.attributes[i].value);
            }
        }
        table.style.cssText = grid.style.cssText;
        table.style.width = parseInt(gridWidth + 17) + "px";
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
        table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0]);
        var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("TH");

        var gridRow = grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            var width;
            if (headerCellWidths[i] > gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth) {
                width = headerCellWidths[i];
            }
            else {

                width = gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth;
            }

            cells[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
            gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
        }
        parentDiv.removeChild(grid);

        var dummyHeader = document.createElement("div");
        dummyHeader.appendChild(table);
        parentDiv.appendChild(dummyHeader);
        //            if (options.Width > 0) {
        //                gridWidth = options.Width;
        //            }
        var scrollableDiv = document.createElement("div");

        gridWidth = parseInt(gridWidth) + 17;

        scrollableDiv.style.cssText = "overflow:auto;height:" + ScrollHeight + "px;width:" + gridWidth + "px";

        scrollableDiv.appendChild(grid);
        parentDiv.appendChild(scrollableDiv);
    });
};})(jQuery);
```

I'm calling the function as below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=grdLog.ClientID %>').Scrollable(400);
}).data("height", 400); ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you properly you want to be able to pass a height into the function call.

Change:

```
var defaults = {
    //ScrollHeight: 400,
    //Height:height,
    Width: 0
};
```

To:

```
var defaults = {
    //ScrollHeight: 400,
    Height: 0,
    Width: 0
};
```

And when you call the function you can now set the height like this:

```
$('#<%=grdLog.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
    Width  : 400,
    Height : 400
});
```

And then you can access `options.Height` and `options.Width` anywhere in your jQuery plugin after the `$.extend()` method call.